Puppet Error: Could not send report: 403 "Forbidden"
On a Debian machine, I try to run Puppet agent with :
puppet agent -t

I have the following error :
root@:/etc/puppet# puppet agent -t
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: 403 "Forbidden"
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': 403 "Forbidden"
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: 403 "Forbidden"
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': 403 "Forbidden"
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: 403 "Forbidden"
Info: Loading facts
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom facts in /var/cache/puppet/lib/facter/user_ssh_pubkey.rb: cannot load such file -- facter/util/file_read
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: 403 "Forbidden"
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: 403 "Forbidden"

Here my auth.conf file :
## Authenticated ACLs - these rules apply only when the client
### has a valid certificate and is thus authenticated

path /puppet/v3/environments
method find
allow *

# allow nodes to retrieve their own catalog
path ~ ^/puppet/v3/catalog/([^/]+)$
method find
allow $1

# allow nodes to retrieve their own node definition
path ~ ^/puppet/v3/node/([^/]+)$
method find
allow $1

# allow all nodes to store their own reports
path ~ ^/puppet/v3/report/([^/]+)$
method save
allow $1

# allow all nodes to update their own facts
path ~ ^/puppet/v3/facts/([^/]+)$
method save
allow $1

# Allow all nodes to access all file services; this is necessary for
# pluginsync, file serving from modules, and file serving from custom
# mount points (see fileserver.conf). Note that the `/file` prefix matches
# requests to both the file_metadata and file_content paths. See "Examples"
# above if you need more granular access control for custom mount points.
path /puppet/v3/file
allow *

path /puppet/v3/status
method find
allow *

# allow all nodes to access the certificates services
path /puppet-ca/v1/certificate_revocation_list/ca
method find
allow *

### Unauthenticated ACLs, for clients without valid certificates; authenticated
### clients can also access these paths, though they rarely need to.

# allow access to the CA certificate; unauthenticated nodes need this
# in order to validate the puppet master's certificate
path /puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca
auth any
method find
allow *

# allow nodes to retrieve the certificate they requested earlier
path /puppet-ca/v1/certificate/
auth any
method find
allow *

# allow nodes to request a new certificate
path /puppet-ca/v1/certificate_request
auth any
method find, save
allow *

# deny everything else; this ACL is not strictly necessary, but
# illustrates the default policy.
path /
auth any



I checked my puppet.conf file on my agent and I compared my auth.conf file on my agent and my master.
